# IntegrityError at /***/ (1048, "Column '***' cannot be null") in python django

Tags: python, django

Hi I am getting this error because I have a field in my [additional user info model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) (`user = models.OneToOneField(User)`) that I am not filling in at sign up (as I want to let the user do it later).

I wondered if there was any way to solve this problem other than allowing null field in the db?

Cheers

Comment: If your user hasn't even provided that yet, do you have to reference the database yet at all?

Comment: I want the object in my additional profile information model class to be created though, even if the information is not provided yet. E.g. I have the standard django user object created but then to provide additional info I have to, according to this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users, create another object for additional user information... I could have something mistaken here...?

Comment: I was following a tutorial here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ba3FYtyjweI&feature=player_detailpage#t=1516s  the guy gets the error in the tutorial but doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: So just make it NULL-able, i.e. `null=True`. You can still leave `blank=False` to make it required in a form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to

`user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True)`

And then recreate your db.
You can find more on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#null

Else you can use Proxy models:

```
class UserExtraInfo(User):
#here your extra fields
```

In this case you won`t need to create UserExtraInfo instance in same time with User.
Read more on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Integrity error occurred basically when you define some database field as not null and pass

the null or blank value

I am assuming you are storing the value in your database by django form

so in that case you can do like

`if request.method == POST:`  # whatever the method

```
   get_form_obj = form.save(commit = False)
```

Don't forget to make change in your model user field like `(null = True,blank = True)`

hope this  will  help

Answer (score 0):

For me it was depth = 1 in serializers.py, just remove this part and the request goes through.  Nested serializers were causing the problem because of this (in console it was showing NestedSerializer(read_only=True):)