# Django Integrity Error "Column 'section_id' cannot be null"

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have seen many questions regarding this error in Django, but I'm at a loss because as far as I can tell, no table in my database has a *section_id* column. I get the error when a user attempts to register and *views.py* attempts to create a user. I recently changed the "Profile" model (*Profile* objects are automatically created alongside *User* objects) in my application to have a *section* attribute rather than a *section_id* attribute, but I reset the migrations and recreated the database several times. I'm thinking that it may be an issue with making the migrations, but I really have no idea.

Here is the profile model that used to have a *section_id* attribute:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    """
    An extension of the built-in Django user model to allow for the different types of users
    """
    USER_TYPES = (
        ('S', 'Student'),
        ('I', 'Instructor'),
        ('C', 'Client')
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=USER_TYPES)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, default=None)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_staff != 1:
        instance.profile.save()
```

And here is the code that is raising the error:

```
new_user = User.objects.create_user(email, email=email, password=password)
```

Comment: "no table in my database has a section_id column", actually it means the `section` column in Profile model. why don't you try `section = models.ForeignKey(Section, blank=True, null=True)`?

Comment: and also set default value for `user_type`

Comment: You're a life saver @AvinashRaj!

Comment: see here also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036400/integrityerror-at-1048-column-cannot-be-null-in-python-django/72588840#72588840

Answer (score 0):

Like Avinash Raj said, setting blank and null to be true for the *section* attribute did the trick:

```
section = models.ForeignKey(Section, blank=True, null=True)
```