# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'category_type' cannot be null")

Tags: python, django

goods.py

```
class Goods(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(GoodsCategory, verbose_name='xxx')
    goods_sn = models.CharField(default='', max_length=50, verbose_name='xxx')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='xxx')
    click_num = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='xxx')
    sold_num = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='xxx')
```

GoodsCategory.py

```
class GoodsCategory(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_TYPE = (
        (1, "Level 1"),
        (2, "Level 2"),
        (3, "Level 3"),
    )
    name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=30, verbose_name="Category name", help_text="Category name")
    code = models.CharField(default="", max_length=30)
    desc = models.TextField(default="", verbose_name="describe")
    category_type = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORY_TYPE, verbose_name="Category Level", help_text="Category Leve")
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, related_name="sub_cat")
    is_tab = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    add_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

import_goods_data.py

```
for goods_detail in row_data:
    goods = Goods()
    goods.name = goods_detail["name"]
    goods.market_price = float(int(goods_detail["market_price"].replace("￥", "").replace("$", "")))
    goods.shop_price = float(int(goods_detail["sale_price"].replace("￥", "").replace("$", "")))
    goods.goods_brief = goods_detail["desc"] if goods_detail["desc"] is not None else ""
    goods.goods_desc = goods_detail["goods_desc"] if goods_detail["goods_desc"] is not None else ""
    goods.goods_front_image = goods_detail["images"][0] if goods_detail["images"] else ""
    category_name = goods_detail["categorys"][-1]
    categories = GoodsCategory.objects.filter(name=category_name) 
    if categories.exists():
        category = categories[0]
    else:
        category = GoodsCategory.objects.create(name=category_name)
    goods.category = category
    goods.save()
```

When I run this script import local data into mysql, I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'category_type' cannot be null")
```

I have tried many times and still haven't solved this problem. Can you help me?

Comment: What's confusing about this? You're creating a GoodsCategory object without specifying the category_type, which is a required field.

Comment: see here also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036400/integrityerror-at-1048-column-cannot-be-null-in-python-django/72588840#72588840

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new `GoodsCategory` you need to explicitly set a `category_type`, set a `default` value or set the field as nullable (`null=True`) in the model. 
[Model field reference #default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#default)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your model a bit, if you want to save empty/null in database.

```
category_type = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORY_TYPE, verbose_name="Category Level", help_text="Category Leve", null=True, default=None)
```