# Django rest IntegrityError: 1048, "Column cannot be null" on foreign key serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have my models defined as following:

```
class Responsibility(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, )

class Collaborator(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, )


class Card(models.Model):
    thing = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null = True, )
    responsibilities = models.ForeignKey(Responsibility, related_name='res_cards', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collaborators = models.ForeignKey(Collaborator, related_name='col_cards', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And serializer:

```
class CollaboratorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Collaborator
        fields = '__all__'

class ResponsibilitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Responsibility
        fields = '__all__'      


class CardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    responsibilities = ResponsibilitySerializer(many=True,)
    collaborators = CollaboratorSerializer(many=True,)

    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        responsibilities_data = validated_data.pop('responsibilities')
        collaborators_data = validated_data.pop('collaborators')

        card = Card.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for responsibility_data in responsibilities_data:
            Responsibility.objects.create(card=card, **track_data)
        for collaborator_data in collaborators_data:
            Collaborator.objects.create(card=card, **track_data)
        return card
```

My POST request looks like following:

```
{u'thing': u'Book', u'responsibilities': [{u'name': u'Name'}, {u'name': u'ISBN'}], u'collaborators': [{u'name': u''}]}
```

But the application throws above error. What am I missing? Responsibilities and Collaborators do not preexist, they will be created along with Card and should also be updated along with Card and not independently.

**UPDATE:** My view for GET and POST

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def card_list(request):
    """
    List all tasks, or create a new card
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cards = Card.objects.all()
        serializer = CardSerializer(cards, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.data)
        serializer = CardSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: why do you have `many=True` on the serializer definitions? These are `ForeignKey` relations so I don't understand why the forward relationship needs `many=True` as each card can only have one responsibility and one collaborator (from the schema you have shared)

Comment: From your question, it looks like you need to associate a single card with multiple responsibilities and collaborators. You should be moving your foreign key to the other tables (resp and collllab) to point back to cards, instead of pointing forward from card.

Comment: see here also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036400/integrityerror-at-1048-column-cannot-be-null-in-python-django/72588840#72588840

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is likely being raised here: `card = Card.objects.create(**validated_data)` - when you are trying to create the `Card` entry; Django expects the `Responsbility` and `Collaborator` Foreign Keys to be present as part of the `validated_data`. This is because the way your schema is defined; the foreign keys are not nullabe; and hence you cannot create a `Card` without the two `ForeignKey` entries.
Change your `Card` model to allow null for `responsibilities` and `collaborators`

```
class Card(models.Model):
    thing = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null = True, )
    responsibilities = models.ForeignKey(Responsibility, related_name='res_cards', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collaborators = models.ForeignKey(Collaborator, related_name='col_cards', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If changing the schema is not an option; reverse your order of operations in the `create` method:

```
for responsibility_data in responsibilities_data:
    resp = Responsibility.objects.create(**responsibility_data)
for collaborator_data in collaborators_data:
    collab = Collaborator.objects.create(**collaborator_data)
validated_data.update({responsibilities: resp.pk, 'collaborators': collab.pk})
card = Card.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

From your question, it looks like you need to associate a single card with multiple responsibilities and collaborators. You should be moving your foreign key to the other tables (resp and collllab) to point back to cards, instead of pointing forward from card.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion helped solve the issue but it is throwing `TypeError: 'card' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`. Is there anything wrong in my code? The card was created but responsibilities and collaborators were saved as bull

Comment: Think the line `esponsibility.objects.create(card=card, **track_data)` expects instead of card something else?

Comment: I think you should read up on foreign key relationships once. You can fix this issue by removing `card=card`. In short, a card has a relationship, the relationship does not have a card.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `null=True` along with `blank=True` on the foreign keys as well.

```
class Card(models.Model):
    thing = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null = True, )
    responsibilities = models.ForeignKey(Responsibility, related_name='res_cards', blank=True,null=True on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collaborators = models.ForeignKey(Collaborator, related_name='col_cards', blank=True, null=True on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```