# IntegrityError 1048: "Column cannot be null"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In a project I have the apps `users` and `comments`, connected via `ForeignKey`.

If I edit a user who doesn't have a comment, I can do that without without any problem. I can even add a comment.

But when I try to save/patch **any** User data of a User that already has a comment, I get the `IntegrityError`.

**EDIT:**
I actually use a `PUT` method both times.

`users\models.py`:

```
    class User(AbstractBaseUser):
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False))
        ....
        #nothing special here
```

`comments\models.py`:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, editable=False, related_name='%(class)s_created', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, editable=False, related_name='%(class)s_modified', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

The Trace in the Error Message points to the line `cmnt.save()` in the function `update` in the `users\serializers.py`, looking like this:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    info = model_meta.get_field_info(instance)

    #extract nested user information to handle those separately
    ...
    ...
    comments_data = validated_data.pop('comments', None)
    ...
    ...

    # update user fields
    
    # Simply set each attribute on the instance, and then save it.
    # Note that unlike `.create()` we don't need to treat many-to-many
    # relationships as being a special case. During updates we already
    # have an instance pk for the relationships to be associated with.
    m2m_fields = []
    for attr, value in validated_data.items():
        if attr in info.relations and info.relations[attr].to_many:
            m2m_fields.append((attr, value))
        else:
            setattr(instance, attr, value)

    instance.save()

    # Note that many-to-many fields are set after updating instance.
    # Setting m2m fields triggers signals which could potentially change
    # updated instance and we do not want it to collide with .update()
    for attr, value in m2m_fields:
        field = getattr(instance, attr)
        field.set(value)

    update_session_auth_hash(self.context.get('request'), instance)

    #create, update, delete related entities

    if comments_data and comments_data is not None:
        #remove items
        cmnt_ids = [item.get('id') for item in comments_data]
        for comment in instance.comments.all():
            if comment.id not in cmnt_ids:
                cmnt.delete()

        #create or update items
        for comment in comments_data:
            cmnt = Comment(owner=instance, **comment)
            cmnt.save()    #  <--- Trace points here
    else:
        #delete all items
        for comment in instance.comments.all():
            comment.delete()
```

The complete Trace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1048, "Column 'created_at' cannot be null")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 114, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 68, in update
    self.perform_update(serializer)
  File "C:\Users\user2\projects\nano_py36dj3\users\views.py", line 135, in perform_update
    serializer.save(modified_by=self.request.user)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 207, in save
    self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\user2\projects\nano_py36dj3\users\serializers.py", line 293, in update
    dig.save()
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 749, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 787, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 920, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 771, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1502, in execute_sql
    cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1154, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user2\Envs\projpy36dj3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 79, in execute
    raise utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args))
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'created_at' cannot be null")
```

in `users\views.py`:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list` and `detail` actions.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsSpecialistAllOrCustomerRead,)

    ...
    ...
  
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        retrieve_type = self.request.query_params.get('retrieve_type', None)

        if retrieve_type is None:
            instance = self.get_object()
            serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
            return Response(serializer.data)

        elif retrieve_type  == 'news_counts' and User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).filter(groups__id=1):
            instance = self.get_object()
            user_id = instance.id

            response_dict = dict()
            sql = """
                 SELECT COUNT(o.id) as requests from projects_project o
                 LEFT JOIN projects_project_participants op ON (o.id = op.project_id)
                 WHERE op.project_id IS NULL;
                """
            response_dict.update(executeRawSQL(sql)[0])

            sql = """
                 SELECT COUNT(r.id) as reminders
                 FROM reminders_reminder r, reminders_reminder_participants rp
                 WHERE r.id = rp.reminder_id AND rp.user_id = {0} AND r.done = 0 AND r.date_time <= CURDATE();
                """.format(*(user_id,))
            response_dict.update(executeRawSQL(sql)[0])

            return Response(response_dict)
        else:
            return Response(dict())



    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if self.request.user.is_anonymous:
            serializer.save()
        else:
            serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(modified_by=self.request.user)  #    <--- Traced to here 

    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        for project in instance.projects.all():
            #print dir(project)
            project.customer = None
            project.save()

        instance.delete()
```

Comment: I will add the complete Trace

Comment: Are you sending a PATCH request or using POST to patch them?

Comment: Please add your viewset and API call

Comment: @Neeraj oh. I see that the AngularJS frontend handles it as PUT, that means POST, right?

Comment: Not same though... PUT method updates everything so it expects every field... while PATCH is for partial updates you can send only one field which is what you want in this particular scenario.. try it with PATCH once using postman .. also if you could share viewset i can suggest more on it.  PS: I meant PUT on previous comment not POST apologies

Comment: i added the ViewSet

Comment: see here also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036400/integrityerror-at-1048-column-cannot-be-null-in-python-django/72588840#72588840

Answer (score 1):

The error arises due to the type of update call made.

PUT method updates all the fields, whereas PATCH is used for updating a single field.
update() method accepts both PUT and PATCH requests and differentiates it using value of "partial".

Since you are using ModelViewSet , it will automatically set partial=True on PATCH request so you need not worry about it. You just need to send a PATCH API call instead of PUT.

For more info on ModelViewSet : [DRF ModelViewSet](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset).

For partial arguments if using other methods in ViewSet : [DEF: Partial Updates](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates)

Comment: Do I understand this right?:
even though I create a new `comment`, Ii should use PATCH, since I'm basically patching `User` data, because they are connected via `ForeignKey`, and because I enter the comment through `UserSerializer`.

Comment: The api call for "But when I try to save/patch any User data of a User that already has a comment" this scenario should be a patch request not put thats what i meant

Comment: I'll have to do try it with only PATCH, or I will have to write a lot of code.
Thank you very much! I hope this solve the problem. I will try it, soon.

Comment: Sure! drop a comment if it still throws an error. It ideally should not :P